# DataJS to Read from ListData.svc not Returning All Fields

Tags: javascript, listdata.svc, external-data-column

I am attempting to use Data.js to read from the ListData.svc but the service is not returning all of the fields that I want. Is there a way that I can specify the view fields or something?

The fields in question are External Data Columns, but they do show up in U2U CamlQuery Builder's results when I am using "connect via web service". I am getting all of the fields **except** these external fields and they do have data in them.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
OData.read(
            "../_vti_bin/listdata.svc/Component_Product_Group_Matrix",
            function (data) {

                componentsList = new Array();
                componentsMatrixDataSource = data.results;
                //Etc.....
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is one of the limitations of the REST API and listdata.svc. See the whole list of [limitations of the listdata.svc](http://allthatjs.com/2012/07/20/limitations-of-sharepoint-listdata-svc/) If you want to get the external list data in javascript you have to you [JavaScript Object Model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh185006%28v=office.14%29.aspx).